# Need to view the entire list elements from success data to html table.(need to view all the elements in the list)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, html-table

I just need to view all the elements in my list from success data to html table.
my list is stored in the model repo so i think its code need not be shown. 
my cshtml page is :

```
@*@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;
    @{List<Customer.Models.Customers> cust = ViewBag.Customers;
        int id = ViewBag.oid;*@
}
<html>
<head>
    <center><h1 style="color:red">New Entries</h1></center>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        FNAME
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        LNAME
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        LOCATION
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        CONTACT
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        EMAIL
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        PASSWORD
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        CATEGORY
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        STATUS
                    </th>

                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                    <tr>

                        <td id="Id"></td>
                        <td id="Fname"></td>
                        <td id="Lname"></td>
                        <td id="Location"></td>
                        <td id="Contact"></td>
                        <td id="Email"></td>
                        <td>**********</td>
                        <td id="Category"></td>
                        <td id="Status"></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="approve" @*onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Approve", "Home", new { cust1.Id})'"*@>Approve/Reject</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="log" @*onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("pro","Home",new { cust1.Id })'"*@>Activity Log</button></td>
                    </tr>
                @*}*@
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="back" @*onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id})'"*@>Back</button></td>
                </tr>



            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

@section Scripts{
<script>
    var id = localStorage.getItem("empid");
    $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:44397/api/Values/Addap",
    success: function (data) {

    res = data;

    document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML = res.id;
    document.getElementById("Fname").innerHTML = res.fname;
    document.getElementById("Lname").innerHTML = res.lname;
    document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML = res.location;
    document.getElementById("Contact").innerHTML = res.contact;
    document.getElementById("Email").innerHTML = res.email;
   // document.getElementById("Password").innerHTML = res.password;
    document.getElementById("Category").innerHTML = res.category;
    document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = res.status;

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#postResult").val(jqXHR.statusText);
    }
    });
    </script>
}
```

Here the value thrown is undefined. 
And I need to see all the values in the list.
can you help me with it. Any additional information can be given on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you returned result is json , you could try the following code:

```
<center><h1 style="color:red">New Entries</h1></center>

<form id="form2">
  <table class="table" id="tbList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FNAME</th>
            <th>LNAME</th>
            <th>LOCATION</th>
            <th>CONTACT</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>

            <th>PASSWORD</th>

            <th> CATEGORY</th>
            <th> STATUS</th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="back">Back</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>

@section Scripts{
  <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://localhost:44343/api/Values/Addap/",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, obj) { 
                    var row = '<tr><td> ' + obj.id + ' </td> <td> '
                        + obj.fname + ' </td> <td>'
                        + obj.lname + '</td> <td>'
                        + obj.location + '</td> <td>'
                        + obj.contact + '</td> <td>'
                        + obj.email + '</td> <td>**********</td> <td>'
                        + obj.category + '</td> <td>'
                        + obj.status + '</td>'
                        +'<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="approve">Approve/Reject</button></td>'
                        +'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="log">Activity Log</button></td> </tr>'
                    $("#tbList tbody").append(row);
                }); 
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Failed!');
            }
        });
  </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Addap()
    {
        var user = await _context.User.ToListAsync();
        return new JsonResult(user);
    }
```